# Flexbox Item in Chrome have wrong height if vertical scrollbar is visible

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

It seems that Google Chrome does not take into account vertical scrollbars of an Flex item first time Flexbox container is rendered.

This is how it look like after page just loaded:

[image: Wrong]

This is how it looks like after changing width of a container a little.

[image: Good]

IE10, IE11 and FF does take into account the scrollbars.

Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/vbarbarosh/pen/myQRwN).

HTML:

```
<div class="subj">
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsuxm dolor sit amet, ...
  </div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.subj {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.subj > :nth-child(1) {
    background: #f88;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.subj > :nth-child(2) {
    background: #8f8;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    border: 5px solid #f8f;
}
.subj > :nth-child(3) {
    background: #88f;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Is there a way to tell Chrome to respect scrollbars?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is casing this issue unfortunately.

But a simple fix is setting the correct height.

On the subj css rule

```
.subj > :nth-child(2)
```

add:

```
overflow:scroll;
```

Comment: `height: calc(2em + 3px)` worked for **this example**. What if the `:nth-child(2)` height will be different (e.g. dynamic)? This is not a solution.

Comment: Found another thing that makes chrome render the content correctly.